# Is there any way to read pdf file by swiping left to move to next page using PdfKit

Tags: ios, swift, pdfkit

[I want to read document from right to left but in this scenario its scrolling from left to right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wgvPO.png)
below is the code I am using to read file but can't read from left side to onward e.g reading book from last page to onward

```
 pdfView.displayMode = .singlePageContinuous
        pdfView.usePageViewController(true, withViewOptions: nil)
        pdfView.pageBreakMargins = UIEdgeInsets(top: 0, left: 0, bottom: 0, right: 0)
        pdfView.displayDirection = .horizontal
        pdfView.displaysAsBook = true
        pdfView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        pdfView.setValue(true, forKey: "forcesTopAlignment")
        pdfView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleHeight,.flexibleWidth,.flexibleTopMargin,.flexibleBottomMargin]
        
        
        pdfView.displayBox = .bleedBox
        
        let temp = JuzzPdfViewController.juzzIndex
        
        let resourse = "parah\(temp)"

        ParahNo = JuzzPdfViewController.juzzIndex
        let fileURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: resourse, withExtension: "pdf")
        
       resumeQuranURl = fileURL
        
        
        pdfView.document = PDFDocument(url: fileURL!)
```

Comment: Can you update your question by pasting / uploading an image of the UI you see now ?

Comment: dude I just want to read pdf file on left scrolling ..I am using pdfkit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
pdfView.displaysRTL = true
pdfView.usePageViewController(true)
```

The `displaysRTL` does not seem to work as well without using the page view controller.

Comment: love you man ...I was just messing with this thing a lot ...you just solved my problem ...appreciate you man ....i marked it as a accepted answer thanks once again